# Concatenate dictionary values in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I created a dictionary in Swift like:

```
var dict:[String : Int] = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4]

print(dict["A"]!)
```

The computer prints number 1, but how do I concatenate these values such that the output is 1234 instead of a single integer?

Answer (score 2):

The key-value pairs in a `Dictionary` are unordered. If you want to access them in a certain order, you must sort the keys yourself:

```
let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2,"C": 3,"D": 4]

let str = dict.keys
            .sorted(by: <)
            .map { dict[$0]! }
            .reduce ("") { $0 + String($1) }
```

Or alternatively:

```
let str = dict.keys
            .sorted(by: <)
            .map { String(dict[$0]!) }
            .joined()
```

No idea about the relative performance of the two as I haven't benchmarked them. But unless your dictionary is huge, the difference will be minimal.

Comment: I'm not sure the OP himself what he wants, but another variation of your method above would be to sort the dict directly, instead of explicitly accessing the (unordered) array of keys for sorting (`let str = dict.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }.reduce("") { $0 + String($1.1) }`).

Comment: @dfri that works as well. If you make that an answer, I will upvote it

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer if you wish, it's really just a variation of your alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

```
let dict = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3, "D": 4]

for entry in dict.sorted()
{
    print("\(entry.1)", terminator: "")
}
```

Comment: Downvote because it doesn't concatenate the string but only the output? :)